# Assign multiple values to variable and proceed with if statement if any of the values matched in list

Tags: python, file, discord.py, hex

What I am trying to do:

```
i = ["FA 3B 65 01", "DA 1C 24 71", "BA 5B 71 21"]

# hexfile = "01 FA 3B 65 01 A2 D2 F1 B3 45 21 C5 C3 BA 5B 71 21 C3 F2 34..."
with open('hexfile', 'r') as file:
   while line := file.read(32):
      if any(i) in line                   #Find "FA 3B 65 01" in first 32bytes
         any(i) = i                       #Assigns "i" to it
            # Do things with i... 
         i = i                            #Reset the value of "i" to original
```

I know this code is non functional currently but this is this way to help me understand the issue I am having, essentially I want to assign multiple values to var `i` and if one of those value is located in my `if` statement then it selects that value and temporarily assigns `i` to it.

Comment: `if any(x in line for x in i)`

Comment: `i = i` doesn't do anything. It just sets the variable to itself, it doesn't reset to a previous value.

Comment: `any(i) = i` is invalid: you can't assign to a function.

Comment: Thank you, I did try ```if any(x in line for x in i)``` before but I don't understand how would I proceed to assign ```i ```to the value that was found in the any() loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `any()` correctly -- it needs to be a sequence of conditions, e.g. `any(x in i if x in line)`.

But `any()` won't tell you which element of the list matched. Instead, you can use a list comprehension to get all the matching elements and test whether this is not empty.

```
with open('hexfile', 'r') as file:
    while line := file.read(32):
        matches = [x in i if x in line]
        if matches:
            match = matches[0] # assuming there's never more than one match
            # do things with match
```

Don't reuse the variable `i`, since there's no way to restore it to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of this:

```
any(i) in line
```

you really want:

```
any((value in line) for value in i)
```

`any(something)` iterates over all values of `something` and evaluates whether any of those values evaluate to `True`.

Therefore you create a generator that gets each value in `i` and tests whether it's in `line` and if any of them are true, processing stops and `any` returns True. Otherwise all values are tested and it returns `False`

Comment: I think he also wants to set a variable to which value was found.